# Google Build Webhook with substitution variables

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am facing some issues using Google Build. I couldn't use the webhook with substitution variables. My code is something like this:

build.sh:

```
gcloud builds submit --config=cloudbuild.yaml --substitutions=_WEBSITE_ID="secretvariables"
```

cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
             curl -d '{"branchName":"development"}' -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud config config-helper --format='value(credential.access_token)')" https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-335148/triggers/12547854-e78a-7418-a2c3-deadinside:run
```

and I got this error here:

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: generic::invalid_argument: key "_WEBSITE_ID" in the substitution data is not matched in the template
```

but I have specified the key for the variable:
[google build trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pphgQ.png)

Any help please?

Comment: Did you try to add a default value in the cloudbuild.yaml and see if the default value or the trigger value is used?

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to use the webhook with substitutions variables by passing in a json file like this:

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
             curl -d '{"branchName":"development"}' -X POST -T request.json -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud config config-helper --format='value(credential.access_token)')" https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<project_id>/triggers/<trigger_uuid>:run
```

request.json:

```
{
 "projectId": "<project_id>",
 "branchName": "development",
 "substitutions": {
  "WEBSITE_ID": "<website_id>"
 }
}
```